# In Python 3, can I retrieve an arbitrary element of a dict without making a list of all of the elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Using Python 3, I would like to get an element (any element) from a dict without making a list of all of the elements.

In Python 2, I did this:

```
next(foo.itervalues())
```

In Python 3, none of these work:

```
next(foo.values())
next(foo.items())
next(foo)
```

Of course I can do this:

```
list(foo.values())[0]
```

but that makes a list of the whole dict before returning the first one.

You cannot assume that I know a key. Also, the dictionary may not be altered.

Comment: `next()` requires an iterator, `foo.value()` is only iterable, use `iter()` to make produce an iterator for it: `next(iter(foo.values()))`.

Comment: Your question is most certainly a duplicate, though. For example [Choose one key arbitrarily in a dictionary without iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37942550/2301450)

Comment: I'll take that one, @vaultah . Thanks!

Comment: @JimHunziker: I didn't dupe to the same post. I duped to a *different* post, one that explains why `next(iter(foo.values()))` works.

Comment: That's fine, @MartijnPieters - the original dupe pointed to was something about getting a random element, but I see you changed it.